# How to pivot_longer with name_pattern in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have multiple variables in my wide-format dataframe with the following structure:

| id | a_column | b_column | c_column | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 122 | 32 | 32 |  |
| 2 | 124 | 22 | 12 |  |
| 3 | 176 | 11 | 86 |  |

I want to pivot_longer it to this (a_ prefix = wave 1, b_prefix = wave 2, c_prefix, = wave 3, d_prefix = wave 4, ...):

| id | index | column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 122 |
| 1 | 2 | 32 |
| 1 | 3 | 32 |
| 2 | 1 | 124 |
| 2 | 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 3 | 12 |
| 3 | 1 | 176 |
| 3 | 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 3 | 86 |

In total, there are several hundred variables that were collected at 10 measurement time points (marked here with "index") and have now been merged into one dataframe. The variables of the first measurement time point have the prefix "a_" (second = "b_", third = "c_") and the last measurement time point with the prefix "j_". To convert the data set from wide to long format, the corresponding variables must therefore be grouped from a_ to j_. I understand that I have to use the cols-argument to keep id (cols = -id) and names_pattern to group variables based on the changing letter prefixes. But I am missing the correct regex and can't identify it. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
df.long <- pivot_longer(df.wide,
                                   cols = -id,
                                   names_pattern = "...",
                                   names_to = .value)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `names_sep = '_'` here, which will split the relevant column names into the two pieces separated by the underscore. We then specify `names_to = c('index', '.value')`, which will place all the pieces to the left of the underscore (i.e. the letters) in a column called `index`. Since there is only a *single* unique string to the right of the underscores, i.e. `column`, the keyword `".value"` will create a *single* column with all the values and call it `column`.

As a final step, we can convert the `index` column from letters to index numbers according to the order they appear using `mutate(index = match(index, unique(index)))`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_sep = "_", names_to = c('index', '.value')) %>%
  mutate(index = match(index, unique(index)))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>      id index column
#>   <int> <int>  <int>
#> 1     1     1    122
#> 2     1     2     32
#> 3     1     3     32
#> 4     2     1    124
#> 5     2     2     22
#> 6     2     3     12
#> 7     3     1    176
#> 8     3     2     11
#> 9     3     3     86
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Question data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, a_column = c(122L, 124L, 176L), b_column = c(32L, 
22L, 11L), c_column = c(32L, 12L, 86L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks, Allan! I should have mentioned that some of the variables have additional "_" in their names. So e.g. "a_column_dv". 

Is that the reason why I get the following error message when I try to execute your code?

1: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 137 rows [1, 3, 10, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 70, 71, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, ...]. 
2: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [85, 466].

Comment: @JamesCraemer what do you want done with those columns? If they are to be included in sequence with the other columns then it would make most sense to rename them. Is that possible?

Comment: In principle yes, but it is a dataset with over 468 variables. Is there perhaps no simpler way that groups the variables with the prefixes a_xxx_xxx to j_xxx_xxx for example? So a_variable_x, b_variable_x, c_variable_x, d_variable_x, ..., as variable_x and a_factor_j, b_factor_j, c_factor_j, ..., as factor_j, etc.? Or perhaps there is a way to do the naming relatively conveniently?

Comment: @JamesCraemer but you still want all the values in a single column? For example, do you want one column called `variable` containing all the values from columns with `variable` in their name, and another column with all the values with `factor` in their name? It seems to me that your actual problem is a little different from the one described in the question. Could you perhaps modify your question to give a more realistic depiction of your naming structure, so that we have some confidence the answer will apply to your own data?

Comment: All right, I have edited the question. I hope it is clearer now. So basically it's about the continuous alphabetical grouping of the variables with the prefixes from a_ to j_ (a_ stands for Wave 1, b_ for Wave 2, c_ for Wave 3, ...).

Comment: @JamesCraemer I already understood that part, that's not what's unclear. What I'm asking is whether the second part of the name should be used to generate columns (i.e. do you want multiple values columns, one for each unique second part of the name?). And what, if anything, do you want done with the third part (after the second underscore) Is this not to be stored anywhere, or is it not relevant? The sample data in the question needs to be similar enough to your own data set so that you can actually apply an answer to your own data. It should be an easy fix if you do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No, the second part in the name of the variable is irrelevant and can be ignored here. To assign the variables to each other, only the consecutive letter prefix ("a_", "b_", ...) plays a role. I had only mentioned it because the very variable names occasionally include another "_" (e.g., "a_column_dv") and I didn't know if that would invalidate the code you posted.

Comment: @JamesCraemer it would be really easy to rename these programmatically in a single step in a pipeline using `rename_with`. Again, without you showing a representative data frame this is hard to do. I can't really help you any more until you have included this in your question, and it really would save a lot of time if you could do this instead of trying to explain it in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Allan Cameron: Thanks a lot for your answer! I followed your advice to rename the variables and it ended up working fine!

I've used the stringr-package with the following code for removing the last "_prefix":

```
names(df) <- str_replace(names(df), "_(prefix)$", "")
```

and the following code for removing the second prefix:

```
names(df) <- str_replace(names(df), "^([a-z])_([a-z]+)$", "\\2_\\1")
names(df) <- str_replace(names(df), "^([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z]+)$", "\\2\\3\\4_\\1")
names(df) <- str_replace(names(df), "^([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)([0-9]+)$", "\\2\\3_\\1")
```

After renaming everything, I've followed your advice using the "sep" argument starting in column 2 with:

```
cols <- ncol(df)
  df_long <- reshape(df, dir = "long", varying = 2:cols, sep = "_")
```

Thank you again for your time!